# How to make "Enemies" orbit around the Player?

Tags: c++, trigonometry, sfml

I'm trying to have enemy sprites orbit around the player sprite when they get near. I'm using the polar coordinates system to find the point at which they should stay. Currently the sprites flicker and dont stay in position correctly and I can't fully figure out why.

The problem seems to arise when using the enemySprite coordinates. When using set numbers there is no flickering and it behaves as expected.

Currently the code sets the position of the enemy to be on the circle instead of moving it there gradually.

```
        for (auto enemyShip = enemyShipStorage.begin(); enemyShip != enemyShipStorage.end();)
        {
            if (!(*enemyShip).isOffScreen)
            {
                //Finding theta in degrees
                //All positions use floats - sf::Vector2f
                float theta = std::atan2((*enemyShip).m_sprite.getPosition().y - player.m_sprite.getPosition().y, (*enemyShip).m_sprite.getPosition().x - player.m_sprite.getPosition().x) * (180 / 3.141f);

                //normalised so 0 is up
                theta -= 90; 

                if (theta < 0)
                {
                    theta += 360;
                }
                else if (theta > 360)
                {
                    theta -= 360;
                }


                //currently using fixed radius distance while testing
                (*enemyShip).m_endPos.x = player.m_sprite.getPosition().x + (400 * std::cos(theta * (3.141f / 180)));
                (*enemyShip).m_endPos.y = player.m_sprite.getPosition().y + (400 * std::sin(theta * (3.141f / 180)));

                //set position to be at the point on the circle
                (*enemyShip).m_sprite.setPosition((*enemyShip).m_endPos);
         }
         ship++
```

The expected result is for the enemies to form a circle around the player without them flickering.

Just want to say thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Minor point, but why the love of degrees?  Stick with Radians will help with random conversion bugs in the future.  Also, it would be nice to know what types the positions and such are.  Finally, setting positions directly is poor game coding.  It tricks the eye because the real work works with forces.  You would be better off giving your enemy ships "impulses" towards a target point - it will look much more realistic in the long run.

Comment: I would also say to debug the output of your position math - make sure the results are the same every single tick.  If they are not, then you have the source of your flickering.  This could be as simple as printf the x/y position every tic and see when it varies.

Comment: Editing the post now to show the types. Could you point me towards anything to do with giving the ships impulses towards a point? It would be interesting to read about as I'm not sure where I would start with something like that. I was using degrees for ease of reading will switch to rads.

Comment: By impulses, I mean applying an acceleration per tic (which with Calculus, basically means adding a value to velocity every tic, then adding the velocity to your position every tic.)  The hard part is knowing when and how to slow down so that you don't overshoot your target.

Comment: It also helps to control the length of your tic so that it doesn't run light speed.  Making your game sync to vblank (vsync) can help limit the speed at which your simulation can run.  You can use other values too though.

Answer (score 0):

You use `(*enemyShip).m_sprite.getPosition()` to get the position, compute some transformation and then use `(*enemyShip).m_sprite.setPosition(...)` to set the position.

Think about it for a second.

Each frame, the enemy ships will jump around to a new position, which you'll transform again. The code does exactly what you asked it to do.

Instead you need two positions. Before and after transformation.

Comment: If I saved the last position how would i go about utilising it to make the function stable. I use getPosition() before the transformation takes place so it shouldn't affect the outcome afterwards. Then next frame it will calculate the transformation again but based on its new position.

Comment: It's not really possible without seeing the rest of the code. How to you spawn enemies, and move them in general ?

Comment: So at the moment I'm just spawning a few enemies on screen. They spawn with different start position. Ive disabled the move function theyre using at the moment so that I can test this function better without it interfering

Comment: Then just replace `theta -= 90; ` with `theta += 1;` the ships will move in circle around your ship, but at a speed dependent on FPS and drift away/closer slowly due to numerical precision.

Comment: It's worth saying that I've noticed the flickering is because of the ship rotating incredibly fast. Even with theta set as +=1 it rotates at a ridiculous speed. When I print the output its seemingly not logical. It goes from 0 to 325.773 then to 2.12 and finally to 55.72. I also want to say thank you for persevering and trying to help. I do appreciate it :)